# R Markdown Variable Displaying as ##NULL in .docx Output

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, docx

I am trying to have a variable display as inline text in my `.docx` output file but unfortunately the value does not appear inline and when I try to display it in a code chunk, I keep getting `"## NULL"` instead of the variable value. The variable value displays correctly in the console, but is not shown in the `.docx` output.

An example of the code followed by the `.docx` output is below.

***R Code***

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

Feedback <- read.csv(file.choose())

E <- (Feedback$E)

"Text is shown here"

"## Title of next paragraph"

"Text that describes the variable that should be displayed:"  `r E`

```

``` {r}
E
```
````

***.docx Output***

Text is shown here

Title of next paragraph is here

Text that describes the variable that should be displayed:

"## NULL"

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that `Feedback$E` exists. Have you tried adding the full path to the file rather than using `file.choose()` - which seems a bit weird to put in an rmarkdown file.